# convert SpEL output to long to use as an annotation argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

Currently, I can use String arguments using `SpEL` as follows:

```java
@Autowired
private ParameterService parameterService;

@Scheduled(cron = "#{parameterService.findByCode('cron')}")
```

It works fine but if I want a long constant it will not be work :

```java
@Autowired
private ParameterService parameterService;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = "#{parameterService.findByCode('fixedDelay')}")
//error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to long

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = Long.parseLong("#{parameterService.findByCode('fixedDelay')}"))
//error: element value must be a constant expression
```

So, How to fix it?

Also, I cannot give **Long** and it accepts only **long**

**edit :**

I have gone through many similar `SpEL` questions but there were **no** applicable solutions for my case.

Comment: can you show the complete error message with stack trace ? and what type does `findByCode` method returns ?

Comment: @Deadpool I added errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fixedDelayString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelayString--) instead:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{parameterService.findByCode('fixedDelay')}"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fixedDelayString](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelayString--) with [spring expression language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{parameterService.findByCode('fixedDelay')}")
```